# Conectar FTP con Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

Estoy haciendo una API con el framework de Lumen y me gustaría subir ficheros de la aplicación a un FTP solo que no he visto ninguna documentación al respecto y quería saber si se sabe de alguna documentación sobre como subir ficheros a un FTP con Lumen.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta función no viene integrada en lumen por defecto como si sucede en laravel, tienes que intalar la librería Flysystem, puedes verificar el proceso en este [tutorial](http://www.sibenye.com/2017/02/16/how-to-integrate-flysystem-with-lumen-framework/)

**Los pasos serian:**

- Instalar mediante composer con el comando: composer require
  graham-campbell/flysystem.
- Requerir el adaptador para ftp    league/flysystem-sftp
- Registrar el proveedor del servicio en
  el archivo bootstrap/app.php agregando esta linea:

> $app->register(GrahamCampbell\Flysystem\FlysystemServiceProvider::class);

- Copie el archivo de configuración flysystem.php del paquete.    Eso
  es copiar el archivo que esta en el directorio vendor/graham-campbell/flysystem/config/flysystem.php a la carpeta
  config.
- En la seccion de ftp, colocas tus datos de acceso:

> 'ftp' => [
>               'driver'     => 'ftp',
>               'host'       => 'ftp.example.com',
>               'port'       => 21,
>               'username'   => 'your-username',
>               'password'   => 'your-password', ]

- Utilizarlo en tu controlador:

> use GrahamCampbell\Flysystem\Facades\Flysystem;
>
> Flysystem::connection('ftp')->read('Archivoasubir.txt');

Comment: Francisco, gracia por tu repuesta. Para que esta tenga mas aceptacion te recomiendo que puedas poner las partes mas importantes del tutorial en tu respuesta, para asi no depender de enlaces externos y aumentar la calidad del sitio.

Comment: Gran aporte, muchas gracias!!